# D-Link DGS-1510-20 torrent QoS related configurtion

Tags: switch, qos, d-link, torrent

I have two options here.

one, I purchased a broken D-Link switch,

and two, there is some sort of QOS or firewall related rules that punish my mac pro from connecting to any other device.

I have a D-Link DGS-1510-20 switch with Boot PROM Version 1.00.012 and Firmware version 1.30.B027, hardware version is A1.

I factory reset the switch and didn't touch any configuration.

I use torrents to download some linux dists, gentoo portage and what not, and after a day or so that Utorrent is running on my mac pro, the download rate decreased, I start losing pings to my own LinkSys router and d-link switch and I can't even connect to my Samsung printer that's connected with an ethernet cable to the switch.

once I reboot the switch without saving settings, it all goes back to normal. just closing utorrent and waiting for 10 minutes resolves the issue two.

I have two CoreOS servers that are connected to the switch with 10GB cables and I didn't notice that they suffer from the same symptoms but I don't really use torrents there.

I tried browsing the d-link switch web interface but all relevant rules by default seems to be turned off.

i just want to make sure I'm not missing something. can anyone please enlighten me regarding this issue ?

Comment: It sounds like you _need_ to configure QoS on you network. QoS needs to be a comprehensive, consistent set of policies configured on all your network devices. Typically, something like torrents would be a bulk-type traffic that has a lower than normal priority. By default, everything has the same priority, and torrents could monopolize your network, which is what it sounds like is happening.

Comment: @RonMaupin - when you mean configured on all my network devices, it means that I should configure QOS on both my linksys router and d-link switch ?

Comment: All the routers and switches that are in your network. It doesn't do any good to only configure it on part of your network, and the configurations must be compatible and consistent on all the network devices. You want to mark traffic as close to the source as possible, so you mark traffic originating on your devices on the access switch interfaces. Also, you have very little control of what comes from the Internet to your WAN router, so there isn't a lot you can do about outsiders clogging your incoming WAN connections - that's why DoS attacks work.

Comment: Did you updated the firmware? I would be curious to see the ram usage before and after when it bug

Comment: @yagmoth555 - i did update the firmware. I'll reproduce the issue and check cpu differences. after rebooting, the cpu is on 15-16%. I'll update here when the problem reoccurs.

Comment: @yagmoth555 - when the problem occurred again the cpu of the dlink was still low, around 16%. closing utorrent and waiting 10 minutes solved the issue as well. what do i do ?